# How to loop over struct properties in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, tuples

Is it possible to iterate over properties of a struct in Swift?

I need to register cells-reuse identifiers in a view controller that makes use of many different cell types (cells are organized in different nib files). So my idea was to put all reuse identifiers and the corresponding nib-files as static tuple-properties (reuseID, nibName) in a struct. But how can I iterate over all of them to register the cells with the tableView?

I already tried something (see my answer below). But is there a more easy way to do this, e.g. without putting every property inside an array?

Comment: Have you been able to do this using the Sequence and IteratorProtocol?

Comment: I never tried. It would be awesome if you could try it out and post an answer here :)

Comment: Ha ha ha! I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921557/how-do-i-make-the-properties-of-a-class-iterable-is-swift-using-sequence-and-ite). It seems using IteratorProtocol is relying on too much technology just for the sake of using technology because it's cool. I still want to do it that way. I got a couple of good questions. I went on to another task for my project, but I still have to come back to this. "matt"'s answer to my question seems to be the most practical. It uses KeyPath.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Although old question, with Swift evolving this question has new answer. I think that you approach is way better for the described situation, however original question was how to iterate over struct properties, so here is my answer(**works both for classes and structs**)

You can use **[Mirror Structure Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html)**. The point is that after calling `reflect` to some object you get it's "mirror" which is pretty sparingly however still useful reflection.

So we could easily declare following protocol, where `key` is the name of the property and `value` is the actual value:

```
protocol PropertyLoopable
{
    func allProperties() throws -> [String: Any]
}
```

Of course we should make use of new protocol extensions to provide default implementation for this protocol:

```
extension PropertyLoopable
{
    func allProperties() throws -> [String: Any] {

        var result: [String: Any] = [:]

        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        guard let style = mirror.displayStyle where style == .Struct || style == .Class else {
            //throw some error
            throw NSError(domain: "hris.to", code: 777, userInfo: nil)
        }

        for (labelMaybe, valueMaybe) in mirror.children {
            guard let label = labelMaybe else {
                continue
            }

            result[label] = valueMaybe
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

So now we can loop over the properties of **any** `class` or `struct` with this method. We just have to mark the class as `PropertyLoopable`.

In order to keep things static(as in the example) I will add also a singleton:

```
struct ReuseID: PropertyLoopable {
    static let instance: ReuseID = ReuseID()
}
```

Whether singleton used or not, we could finally loop over the properties like follows:

```
do {
    print(try ReuseID.instance.allProperties())
} catch _ {

}
```

And that's it with looping struct properties. Enjoy swift ;)

Comment: You could replace that loop with `let properties = mirror.children.filter { $0.label != nil }.map { $0.label! }`

Comment: In Swift 2 you can make it even shorter with flatMap: `let properties = mirror.children.flatMap { $0.label }`

Comment: But you it does not print static properties. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I have the same question @blackjacx, I think I will make another post.

Comment: @blackjacx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339250/iterate-over-static-properties-of-a-struct

Comment: doesn't seem to work with static let struct properties.

Comment: What about changing the value of a property?

Comment: Could this be used to copy structs while changing a single property?

Answer (score 23):

Using **hris.to**'s awesome answer, I wanted to provide a **Swift 3** answer that's more to the point and doesn't use singletons.

### Protocol & Extension:

```
protocol Loopable {
    func allProperties() throws -> [String: Any]
}

extension Loopable {
    func allProperties() throws -> [String: Any] {

        var result: [String: Any] = [:]

        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        // Optional check to make sure we're iterating over a struct or class
        guard let style = mirror.displayStyle, style == .struct || style == .class else {
            throw NSError()
        }

        for (property, value) in mirror.children {
            guard let property = property else {
                continue
            }

            result[property] = value
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

#### Example:

```
struct Person: Loopable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

var bob = Person(name: "bob", age: 20)

print(try bob.allProperties())

// prints: ["name": "bob", "age": 20]
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but it is possible to iterate over `static` properties?

Answer (score 15):

Now there's a much easier way to do this:

1: Create an Encodable protocol extension:

```
extension Encodable {
    var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
    }
}
```

2: Make your struct/class conform to Encodable protocol

```
struct MyStruct: Encodable {...}
class MyClass: Encodable {...}
```

And then you can get a Dictionary representing your struct/class instance at any time:

```
var a: MyStruct
var b: MyClass

print(a.dictionary)
print(b.dictionary)
```

And then you can loop through the keys:

```
for (key, value) in a.dictionary { ... }
for (key, value) in b.dictionary { ... }
```

Comment: got two errors trying this: For-in loop requires '[String : Any]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?, and Tuple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type '_'

Comment: Yes, this is just simplified, you should either do the check: if let dic = a.dictionary {...} or force unwrap (not recommeded)

Answer (score 7):

I made a recursive function based on @John R Perry's solution that goes deeper into properties that are objects. It also takes an parameter to limit how many levels deep it goes (default is `Int.max`) to help prevent stackoverflow's:

```
protocol Loopable {
    func allProperties(limit: Int) [String: Any]
}

extension Loopable {
    func allProperties(limit: Int = Int.max) [String: Any] {
        return props(obj: self, count: 0, limit: limit)
    }

    private func props(obj: Any, count: Int, limit: Int) -> [String: Any] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
        var result: [String: Any] = [:]
        for (prop, val) in mirror.children {
            guard let prop = prop else { continue }
            if limit == count {
                result[prop] = val
            } else {
                let subResult = props(obj: val, count: count + 1, limit: limit)
                result[prop] = subResult.count == 0 ? val : subResult
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

I got rid of the check for if the object is a `class` or `struct` because that the parameter not being a `class` or `struct` is the base case of the recursive function, and it was easier to handle it manually than with errors.

Testing it:

```
class C {
    var w = 14
}
class B: Loopable {
    var x = 12
    var y = "BHello"
    var z = C()
    static func test() -> String {
        return "Test"
    }
}
class A: Loopable {
    var a = 1
    var c = 10.0
    var d = "AHello"
    var e = true
    var f = B()
    var g = [1,2,3,4]
    var h: [String: Any] = ["A": 0, "B": "Dictionary"]
    var i: Int?
}
print(A().allProperties())
```

prints:

```
["e": true, "g": [1, 2, 3, 4], "f": ["z": ["w": 14], "x": 12, "y": "BHello"], "h": ["A": 0, "B": "Dictionary"], "c": 10.0, "i": nil, "d": "AHello", "a": 1]
```

(Dictionaries are unordered, so if you get a different order, that's why)

Answer (score 4):

```
struct IdentifiersModel : Codable {
    let homeReuseID: String = "Home_Reuse_ID"
    let offersReuseID: String =  "Offers_Reuse_ID"
    let testReuseID: String =  "Test_Reuse_ID"

    func toDic() -> [String:Any] {
        var dict = [String:Any]()
        let otherSelf = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in otherSelf.children {
            if let key = child.label {
                dict[key] = child.value
            }
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

Create a new instance from the struct and call toDic() function

```
 let identifiersModel = IdentifiersModel()
  print(identifiersModel.toDic())
```

Output:

```
["offersReuseID": "Offers_Reuse_ID", "testReuseID": "Test_Reuse_ID", "homeReuseID": "Home_Reuse_ID"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of iterating over struct properties (reuse identifiers of UITableViewCells and the corresponding NIB-names) using Swifts tuple feature. This is useful if you like organizing your cells in nib files and have a UIViewController that makes use of many different cell types.

```
struct ReuseID {
  static let prepaidRechargeCreditCell = "PrepaidRechargeCreditCell"
  static let threeTitledIconCell = "ThreeTitledIconCell"
  static let usageCell = "UsageCell"
  static let detailsCell = "DetailsCell"
  static let phoneNumberCell = "PhoneNumberCell"

  static let nibNamePrepaidRechargeCreditCell = "PrepaidRechargeCreditCell"
  static let nibNameThreeTitledIconCell = "IconCellWith3Titles"
  static let nibNameUsageCell = "ListElementRingViewCell"
  static let nibNameDetailsCell = "ListElementStandardViewCell"
  static let nibNamePhoneNumberCell = "PhoneNumberCell"

  static let allValuesAndNibNames = [
    (ReuseID.prepaidRechargeCreditCell, ReuseID.nibNamePrepaidRechargeCreditCell),          
    (ReuseID.threeTitledIconCell, ReuseID.nibNameThreeTitledIconCell), 
    (ReuseID.usageCell, ReuseID.nibNameUsageCell), 
    (ReuseID.detailsCell, ReuseID.nibNameDetailsCell), 
    (ReuseID.phoneNumberCell, ReuseID.nibNamePhoneNumberCell)]
}
```

With that struct it is easy to register all cell types using a for-loop:

```
for (reuseID, nibName) in ReuseID.allValuesAndNibNames {
    if let xibPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(nibName, ofType: "nib") {
        let fileName = xibPath.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension
        self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: fileName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseID)

    } else {
        assertionFailure("Didn't find prepaidRechargeCreditCell ")
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not iterating over struct properties. If it was, adding new property should automatically return it by `allValuesAndNibNames`. I think the answer right now is NO.

Comment: As for the example, the entire code can be removed using a storyboard, which is a much better solution.

Comment: frankly this is better practice than relying on Reflection for implementation

Answer (score 3):

Knowing that in Swift 1.2 you could use `reflect()`, and since Swift 2 you can use [`Mirror`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror), here is an addition to **hris.to**'s answer for Swift 3 and 4.

```
protocol Loopable {
    var allProperties: [String: Any] { get }
}
extension Loopable {
    var allProperties: [String: Any] {
        var result = [String: Any]()
        Mirror(reflecting: self).children.forEach { child in
            if let property = child.label {
                result[property] = child.value
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Usage on any struct or class:

```
extension NSString: Loopable {}

print("hello".allProperties)
// ["_core": Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: Optional(0x00000001157ee000), _countAndFlags: 5, _owner: nil)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that RPatel99's answer worked the best for me, but it did not handle the case where there as an array of Loopables inside another Loopable.

Here is a version that fixes that issue.

```
protocol Loopable {
    func allProperties(limit: Int) -> [String: Any]
}

extension Loopable {
    func allProperties(limit: Int = Int.max) -> [String: Any] {
        return props(obj: self, count: 0, limit: limit)
    }

    private func props(obj: Any, count: Int, limit: Int) -> [String: Any] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
        var result: [String: Any] = [:]
        for (property, value) in mirror.children {
            var val = value

            if let values = value as? [Loopable] {
                var vals = [Any]()
                for val in values {
                    vals.append(val.allProperties())
                }
                val = vals
            }
            
            guard let prop = property else { continue }
            
            
                if limit == count {
                    result[prop] = val
                } else {
                    let subResult = props(obj: val, count: count + 1, limit: limit)
                    result[prop] = subResult.count == 0 ? val : subResult
                }
            }
        
        return result
    }
}

class C {
    var w = 14
}
class B: Loopable {
    var x = 12
    var y = "BHello"
    var z = C()
    static func test() -> String {
        return "Test"
    }
}
class A: Loopable {
    var a = 1
    var c = 10.0
    var d = "AHello"
    var e = B()
    var f = [B(), B(), B()]
    var g = [1,2,3,4]
    var h: [String: Any] = ["A": 0, "B": B().allProperties()]
    var i: Int?
}
print(A().allProperties())
```

The result I get is this
["h": ["A": 0, "B": ["z": ["w": 14], "y": "BHello", "x": 12]], "e": ["y": "BHello", "z": ["w": 14], "x": 12], "f": [["y": "BHello", "z": ["w": 14], "x": 12], ["x": 12, "z": ["w": 14], "y": "BHello"], ["y": "BHello", "x": 12, "z": ["w": 14]]], "i": nil, "g": [1, 2, 3, 4], "a": 1, "d": "AHello", "c": 10.0]

I hope someone else will find this useful.
This result could probably also be achieved by something like this