# Reflection: get static vars of class in Swift?

Tags: swift, reflection, swift4

Given a simple class like:

```
class Foo {
    static var can: String? { didSet { 5+4 } }
    static let haz: String
}
```

How do I implement a method within `Foo` that enumerates over `can` and `haz`; without explicitly writing them out again? - E.g.: so I can `print("key: '\(key\)' has value: '\(value)'")`

---

BTW: Noticed this: [How to loop over struct properties in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27292255); but couldn't get it to work for `static`.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out @A T ?