# How to get all property names in nested Structs

Tags: swift, struct, properties

Lets assume I have the following struct:

```
struct Location: Codable, Loopable {
    var altitude: Double?
    var coordinate: Coordinate?
    struct Coordinate: Codable, Loopable {
        var latitude: Double?
        var longitude: Double?
    }
    var course: Double?
    var courseAccuracy: Double?
    var floor: Floor?
    struct Floor: Codable, Loopable {
        var level: Int?
    }
    var horizontalAccuracy: Double?
    var speed: Double?
    var speedAccuracy: Double?
    var timestamp: Timestamp?
    struct Timestamp: Codable, Loopable {
        var year: Int?
        var month: Int?
        var day: Int?
        var hour: Int?
        var minute: Int?
        var second: Int?
    }
    var verticalAccuracy: Double?
    var deviceName: String?
    var validPosition: Bool?
}
```

Now I want to implement two methods for structs. One should return all property names with all parents in its name and the other one should return all values of these properties.

The result should look like this for the first method (lets name it allProperties()):

`["altitude", "coordinate.latitude", "coordinate.longitude", "course", "courseAccuracy", "floor.level", "horzontalAccuracy", "speed", "speedAccuracy", "timeststamp.year", "timestamp.month", "timestamp.day", "timeststamp.hour", "timestamp.minute", "timestamp.second", "verticalAccuracy", "deviceName", "validPosition"]`

The result of the second method (lets name it allValues()) should look like this:

`[500.0, 48.000000, 10.00000, 120.0, 5.0, 4, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2021, 07, 25, 22, 43, 50, 10.0, "iPhone", true]`

As you can see my example struct is nested with other structs. In my real project, the structs have more than two nested "levels". Also the property types are not unique. On the very bottom level they are all basic data types (Double, Bool, String, Int).

I tried to modify the solution for parsing nested structs with an recursive approach from this thread, which seems to be an elegant solution: [How to loop over struct properties in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292255/how-to-loop-over-struct-properties-in-swift/56675017#56675017)

Now my problem:

- The method for the property names only gives an array with "some" back.
- But the method for the property values returns the correct Array

`["some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some", "some"]`

This was my code for the protocol so far:

```
protocol Loopable {
    func allProperties(limit: Int) -> [String]
    func allValues(limit: Int) -> [Any]
}

extension Loopable {
    func allProperties(limit: Int = Int.max) -> [String] {
        return props(obj: self, count: 0, limit: limit)
    }
    
    func allValues(limit: Int = Int.max) -> [Any] {
        return values(obj: self, count: 0, limit: limit)
    }

    private func props(obj: Any, count: Int, limit: Int) -> [String] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
        var result: [String] = []
        for (prop, val) in mirror.children {
            guard let prop = prop else { continue }
            if limit == count {
                result.append(prop)
            } else {
                let subResult = props(obj: val, count: count + 1, limit: limit)
                subResult.count == 0 ? result.append(prop) : result.append(contentsOf: subResult)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    
    private func values(obj: Any, count: Int, limit: Int) -> [Any] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
        var result: [Any] = []
        for (_, val) in mirror.children {
            //guard let val = val else { continue }   // This line does not compile
            if limit == count {
                result.append(val)
            } else {
                let subResult = values(obj: val, count: count + 1, limit: limit)
                subResult.count == 0 ? result.append(val) : result.append(contentsOf: subResult)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why are the property labels always "some"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue with the `“some”` stems from your values being optional, optional values are an enumeration so your reflection is picking that up. This is why you cannot perform the guard in `private func values(obj: Any, count: Int, limit: Int) -> [Any]` as you are not unwrapping to a concrete type.

As all your subtypes confirm to `Loopable` we can refactor your code to check if the type conforms to `Loopable`. It is also more efficient to check if something is empty than if its count is equal to zero, so you should use that property where you can.

We’re now using the `prop` value as a prefix so that we can get the name that you are looking for, however, because your values are optional they are wrapped in an enum so you have to strip the `.some` from the string. The type of `val` is `Any`, this means we cannot unwrap it if it is an optional without knowing what its concrete type is, hence we need to do the above dance to remove the `.some` from the prefix.

```
import Foundation


protocol Loopable {
    func allProperties() -> [String]
}

extension Loopable {
    func allProperties() -> [String] {
        return props(obj: self)
    }
    
    private func props(obj: Any, prefix: String = "") -> [String] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
        var result: [String] = []
        for (prop, val) in mirror.children {
            guard var prop = prop else { continue }
   
            // handle the prefix
            if !prefix.isEmpty {
                prop = prefix + prop
                prop = prop.replacingOccurrences(of: ".some", with: "")
            }
   
            if let _ = val as? Loopable {
                let subResult = props(obj: val, prefix: "\(prop).")
                subResult.isEmpty ? result.append(prop) : result.append(contentsOf: subResult)
            } else {
                result.append(prop)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Here is a simple struct that we can test the above code with.

```
struct User: Loopable {
    let name: String
    let age: Age?
    
    struct Age: Loopable {
        let value: Int?
        let day: Day?
        
        struct Day: Loopable {
            let weekday: Int?
        }
    }
}

let user = User(name: "mike", age: .init(value: 20, day: .init(weekday: 5)))

print(user.allProperties())
```

This will print out the following

`["name", "age.value", "age.day.weekday"]`

Comment: thank you very much for your solution and the explanation. I think I have to read more documentation about this optional value types to better understand, why they are enums.

Comment: Why is the output of your solution following the order (from top to bottom) of the properties in your struct?  In the thread mentioned above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292255/how-to-loop-over-struct-properties-in-swift/56675017#56675017) the order of the output is random. I just want to understand this nice feature of your solution?

Comment: Here’s Apple’s documentation on optionals https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional The output is random in the answer you link to because it uses a dictionary, dictionaries do not guarantee order. In my answer (based off of your code) we are using an array and arrays are ordered.