# How do I make the properties of a class iterable is swift using Sequence and IteratorProtocol?

Tags: swift, class, properties

I would like to make my class in Swift iterable.

My goal is to be able to create a class called Contact that holds properties such as the givenName, familyName, and middleName, like iOS CNContact. I would like to be able to have a class function that compares two instances of the class Contact, and finds which property the two contact objects have that match, so that say if both contacts have the same value for the givenName property, then the class function returns the result.

Here is a sample code:

```
class Contact {
    
    static func compare(left: Contact, right: Contact) {
        
        for property in left.properties {
            if property == right.property {
                // match is found
            }
        }

    }
    
    var givenName: String = ""
    var familyName: String = ""
    var middleName: String = ""
    
    private var properties = [givenName, familyName, middleName]
    
}

let left = Contact()
let right = Contact()

Contact.compare(left: left, right: right)
```

I found posts that used mirroring and reflection, but I want to use Sequence and IteratorProtocol. I suspect there is already the ability to do exactly what I want to do. It seems to be a logical need that would arise.

What is the way to do this that has a balance between simplicity and the ability to address common needs to iterate through the instance properties of a class. An enumeration can be declared with given has values. Is there a way to make that work for this purpose? Is there a protocol that a class can use that assigns a hash value or other identifiable value that would allow for a sequential order to iterate through the properties of a class?

I was able to find posts and documentation that allowed me to get as far as the following code in playground that generated the following in debug window:

```
struct Name: Sequence {
    typealias Iterator = NameIterator
    typealias Element = Name
    typealias Name = String
    
    var name = "<name>"
    
    func makeIterator() -> NameIterator {
        return NameIterator()
    }
}

struct NameIterator: IteratorProtocol {
    typealias Iterator = String
    typealias Element = Name
    typealias Name = String

    mutating func next() -> Name? {
        
        let nextName = Name()
        
        return nextName
    }
    
}

let nameStrings = ["Debbie", "Harper", "Indivan", "Juniella"]

for nameString in nameStrings {
    print(nameString)
}
```

> 

```
Debbie
Harper
Indivan
Juniella
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what your ultimate goal looks like? Your code is very confusing - you can *already* do `for nameString in nameStrings { ... }` without any of those `Name` and `NameIterator` stuff at the start. What are their purpose, anyway? Right now they produce an infinite sequence of empty strings...

Comment: And why don't you want to use a mirror?

Comment: @Sweeper Ok. I just put a description of what I want to be able to do with a class and a sample code. My original code is confusing because I didn't know what the typealias statements for Element and Iterator were for. I didn't look closely at what Element referred to. Come to think of it, Element might mean the thing that is being iterated. The code I put up there for struct Name and struct NameIterator is an early attempt of trying something new.

Comment: @Sweeper I have no good reason for not wanting to use mirror. Sequence and IteratorProtocol seemed like a more advanced way to me for reasons I'm not sure of. I think I am biased toward those two protocols because I have seen "Sequence" before.

Comment: Have you heard about key paths?

Comment: @matt I think key paths have to do with Key Value Coding and Key Value Observing? Am I right?

Comment: No, Swift key paths are unrelated to Cocoa KVC.

Comment: @matt I have heard of key paths, but just in passing while I was trying to learn something else. How does key paths work for what I want to do?

Comment: As an alternative to using key paths, even just changing `properties` into a computed property would make your first code snippet work. Contact info is not a sequence of properties - you should not conform to `Sequence`.

Comment: @Sweeper How do I use a computed property to do what you mean?

Comment: @Sweeper It seems a good idea to use prescribed and established ways set by Apple. It makes my code more consistent with other Apple ways and might save trouble later should my code ever go further than I thought it would. Just thinking ahead without really being sure why doing things Apple's way will ever really benefit me. Thinking safely about the furture.

Comment: "How does key paths work for what I want to do?" Well, you expressed a desire (I thought) to cycle thru the properties of an object, comparing each property in one instance with the same property in another instance. A list of key paths is how you do that.

Comment: "and finds which property the two contact objects have that match, so that say if both contacts have the same value for the givenName property, then the class function returns the result." What's "the result"? Your hypothetical example has no rreturn type or return value. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Alexander Ah. Yes. If the two contacts match, (they would specifically be CNContact objects), then my code would inform the user that they can merge the two CNContact objects. I haven't found any API's that enables my code to compare a CNContact object from a vCard with other CNContact objects from the CNContactStore to determine whether the object from the vCard are likely referring to the same person as another object from the contact store.

Comment: @daniel It looks to me like neither Mirror nor Sequence are relevant to your problem. Mirror would be useful for being able to write code that finds all the properties of an object (dynamically with reflection, instead a hard-coded list you hand-crafted for a specific type), but you're only concerned with doing this one-off for your `Contact` class. `Sequence` would be useful for making an object into a custom sequence/iterator, such as to lazy load its properties rather than reading them eagerly. This isn't necessary for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't want to use mirror, a straightforward way is to cycle through a list of key paths. This is particularly easy in your case because the properties are all strings:

```
class Contact {
    static let properties = [\Contact.givenName, \Contact.familyName, \Contact.middleName]

    static func compare(left: Contact, right: Contact) {
        for property in properties {
            if left[keyPath: property] == right[keyPath: property] {
                print("got a match"); return
            }
        }
        print("no match")
    }

    var givenName: String = ""
    var familyName: String = ""
    var middleName: String = ""
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I found the documentation for [Key-Path Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/key-path-expressions). It didn't show how KeyPath is used. It's part of the Swift standard library. I didn't know you can do that with Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some confusion going on here.

The `Sequence` protocol and friends (`IteratorProtocol`, `Collection`, etc.) exist for you to be able to define custom sequences/collections that can leverage the existing collection algorithms (e.g. if you conform to `Sequence`, your type gets `map` "for free"). It has absolutely nothing to do with accessing object properties. If you want to do that, the only official reflection API in Swift is `Mirror`.

It's possible to...

1. ...just `Mirror`, to create a standard collection (e.g. `Array`) of properties of an object
2. ...just `Sequence`/`Collection`, to create a custom collection object that lists the property values of an object from hard-coded keypaths
3. ...or you can use both, together, to create a custom collection object that uses `Mirror` to automatically list the properties of an object and their values